# Android Oreo: what should I do to publish my app as an Autofill service provider?

Tags: android, passwords, autofill, android-8.0-oreo

I'm an independent developer of a password manager app. What should I do, or what should I implement (interface/API/Service), to make my app an Autofill service provider (in a device with Android Oreo API >= 26)?

I have read all kinds of related documentation, but I can't understand how to do this. Am I missing something?

At the moment I see that only well-known password managers support this feature:

[image: Image of apps that provide Autofill service]

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Did you look at their sample project ? https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AutofillFramework

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-os-autofill-framework--cms-28811

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As usual, Google's own [examples repository provides a good starting point](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AutofillFramework/tree/master/afservice) for learning the Autofill Framework's API, and covers much more material than I can fit into an answer. Here's an overview of the key concepts. From the description in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill.html), we want to create an Autofill *service* that will handle requests from other apps (the clients) to store and retrieve Autofill field data.

First, we need to create a service provider class that fulfills this contract. We can extend the base [`AutofillService` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/AutofillService.html):

```java
import android.service.autofill.AutofillService;
...
public class MyAutofillService extends AutofillService {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onFillRequest(FillRequest request, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
        FillCallback callback) { ... }

    @Override
    public void onSaveRequest(SaveRequest request, SaveCallback callback) { ... }
}
```

The service's [`onFillRequest()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/AutofillService.html#onFillRequest(android.service.autofill.FillRequest,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20android.service.autofill.FillCallback)) and [`onSaveRequest()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/AutofillService.html#onSaveRequest(android.service.autofill.SaveRequest,%20android.service.autofill.SaveCallback)) methods are the most significant for our understanding. The Android system calls `onFillRequest()` to determine if our service can autofill fields for a particular activity, and gives the method a [`FillRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/FillRequest.html) which contains the context and view information that our service will examine for fillable fields. When the service finishes, it invokes the provided `callback` with the appropriate autofill data.

Here's a *dramatically* simplified overview of the basic steps needed to provide autofill suggestions for a `FillRequest`:

```
@Override
public void onFillRequest(FillRequest request, CancellationSignal signal, FillCallback callback) {
    List<FillContext> contexts = request.getFillContexts();
    AssistStructure structure = contexts.get(contexts.size() - 1);
    WindowNode windowNode = structure.getWindowNodeAt(0);
    ViewNode viewNode = windowNode.getRootViewNode(); // pretend this is an EditText

    String suggestionText = "This will appear in the autofill list for 'viewNode'.";
    RemoteViews suggestion = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.autofill_suggestion);
    suggestion.setTextViewText(R.id.autofill_suggestion, suggestionText);

    Dataset suggestionDataset = new Dataset.Builder(suggestion) 
        .setValue(viewNode.getAutoFillId(), AutofillValue.forText(suggestionText))
        .build();

    FillResponse response = new FillResponse.Builder() 
        .addDataset(suggestionDataset)
        .build();

    callback.onSuccess(response);
}
```

As we can see, the Autofill API requires a lot of code just to provide a single, static autofill suggestion for a `View` that we already know in advance—the example assumes that `viewNode` is a text input field that we want to provide autofill suggestions for. In reality, this example is too simple, but I wanted to clearly show the minimum implementation. For each `WindowNode`, we need to walk through the view tree of the root [`ViewNode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/assist/AssistStructure.ViewNode.html) and each of its children to find each of the input fields that our service wishes to provide autofill data for, and then create a [`RemoteViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) and [`Dataset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/Dataset.html) that contains the autofill suggestion for each field that we'll add to the [`FillResponse`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/FillResponse.html) using [`FillResponse.Builder.addDataset()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/FillResponse.Builder.html). This example doesn't show the plain XML layout for the `R.layout.autofill_suggestion` `TextView` used to create the suggestion display item for a `RemoteViews`.

Similarly, Android calls `onSaveRequest()` when a user wants to save the data in an activity's fields for future completion requests and injects a [`SaveRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/SaveRequest.html) that our service uses to find autofill data to remember.

The specific implementation of each of these methods will depend on the type of Autofill data that our app provides. Autofill services *must* conscientiously examine the characteristics of each field and *carefully* select a set of appropriate autofill suggestions to avoid leaking the user's data to a malicious client activity (see comments). For a password manager in particular, we need to pay special attention to properly authenticating a user of the service and providing a safe set of suggestions when requesting and saving autofill data.

We can now [register the service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) in the `<application>` block of the project's *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```xml
<service
    android:name=".MyAutofillService"
    android:label="Multi-Dataset Autofill Service"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.autofill"
        android:resource="@xml/multidataset_service" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.autofill.AutofillService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

As shown, this binds our Autofill service as an available option that appears in the Autofill services list show in the question. The `android:name` attribute must match the name of our `AutofillService` class, and our app must declare the `BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE` permission. Change the value of `android:label` to a suitable name for the service (for example, "Autofill with Password Manager"). Alternatively, set this in a string resource. Note also that we should provide a "settings" activity used to configure our service which we specify in the `<meta‑data>` for `android.autofill`:

```xml
<autofill-service android:settingsActivity="foo.bar.SettingsActivity" />
```

Then, the user can enable our Autofill service from their device Settings. We can broadcast the [`ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE) intent during setup or first launch to assist the user in finding this screen.

Comment: In addition to what is cited here, bear in mind that it is *your* job, not Google's, [to implement appropriate security](https://github.com/commonsguy/AutofillFollies/blob/master/WHITE_PAPER.md) (e.g., to not leak data to malicious activities).

Comment: Quoting @CommonsWare's white paper: **"Autofill will fill in widgets that the user cannot see...[or]...a widget that does not exist at all in the view hierarchy, but rather is faked by the activity..."** - This *should* alarm any developers building an autofill service into carefully considering how their service chooses when to supply a user's data.

Comment: Ok. I will take care these considerations - thanx!

Comment: Bumping this as this seems related enough to not warrant a new question, but I tried running the xamarin autofill sample: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/android-o/AutofillFramework, which seems to hit all the requirements laid out in this answer, and yet in the autofill service selection page it does not show up. Granted this sample targets API 27 and now we have to target 30 at minimum according to VS 2022, but I get no errors during runtime, I just don't see the service in the settings. Has anyone run into this?