# Custom Android Autofill service doesn't appear in autofill apps

Tags: android, android-studio, autofill

I've built an Autofill service following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-os-autofill-framework--cms-28811) guide. I'm running it on a Pixel API 27 emulator via Android Studio.

Here is my manifest file:`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service android:name=".EmailAddressFiller"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_AUTO_FILL">
        <meta-data android:name="android.autofill"
            android:resource="@xml/email_address_filler"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.autofill.AutofillService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Yet, when I go to Settings > System > Languages & Input > Autofill service,
I don't see my custom service as an option.

Would love to hear any idea on the issue here.

Comment: I got a similar Answer [Autofill Service Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367576/android-oreo-what-should-i-do-to-publish-my-app-as-an-autofill-service-provider)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Oreo: what should I do to publish my app as an Autofill service provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367576/android-oreo-what-should-i-do-to-publish-my-app-as-an-autofill-service-provider)

Answer (score 0):

1. EmailAddressFiller class must inherit from AutofillService class
2. As of Android 12, android:exported must be set:
   android:exported="true" (true in order to export this service to other apps)