# How to build an autofill service in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-service, autofill

I'm a newbie programmer and want to build an autofill service which populates the `RemoteViews` using Firebase Realtime Database for a personal Password Manager project. I followed the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services). However, I'm unable to understand the advanced functionality classes like the `Auth` class and `PackageVerifier` class. I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47409546/13855858), but this implementation is too basic.

My app stores usernames and passwords on Firebase Realtime Database. It would be of great help if someone could provide a guide to achieve the desired functionality.

It would be great if someone could provide a simplified guide. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good guide, but it is limited. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-os-autofill-framework--cms-28811